# Topology Configuration on CheckPoint

Tags: ip-spoofing, configuration, check-point

On CheckPoint firewall (R77), in the Topology config. section that is used for anti-spoofing, is it possible to configure 2 different **External** interfaces?

I have already an interface configured as External for an internet access via a remote datacenter.

But now I have a new local internet access on another interface for a part of my local users, and I wonder if I can configure another External interface.

I don't really understand the differences between an Internal and an External interface in term of anti-spoofing process.

Comment: Might be better to call/email Checkpoint for technical support or go to their forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On Check Point firewall (R77), in the Topology config. section that is
>   used for anti-spoofing, is it possible to configure 2 different
>   External interfaces ?

It is possible - for example, [this document on ISP Redundancy in R77](https://sc1.checkpoint.com/documents/R77/CP_R77_SecurityGatewayTech_WebAdmin/89364.htm) clearly describes that case:

> If the Security Gateway has two external interfaces in the Topology
>   page of the gateway object, you can configure the links automatically.

And this snippet of a [CCSA Exam Cram](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=387728&seqNum=5) states:

> - You can have multiple interfaces defined as external.
>
> ...In [this] case, the same behavior of calculating external topology
>   applies to all externally defined interfaces—that is, any network not
>   included on any of the internal interfaces is valid on all external
>   interfaces.

However, there may be complications.  For example, there's a specific setting to make it break less stuff: "[Support connectivity enhancement for gateways with multiple external addresses](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk30950)".  To quote a portion of it:

> The problem is that the VPN-1 Gateway needs a routing mechanism that
>   can route packets, returned to the Office Mode IP addresses, to the
>   appropriate external router when the VPN-1 Gateway has two external
>   interfaces, based on from which VPN-1 Gateway external IP address the
>   SecureClient Office Mode connections came.
>
> The option "Support connectivity enhancement for gateways with
>   multiple external interfaces" addresses this specific need.

There also used to be an issue where an Unlimited license was required for traffic to [route across the two external interfaces](https://www.cpug.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-9349.html).  That thread's 10 years old now, though, so take that with a grain of salt.

I haven't had significant CheckPoint console time for 10 years myself, but my recollection is that when I was working with it, I worked a few implementations that had multiple external interfaces, without any particular problems*.

*...due to the multiple interfaces.